# Basic Java arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

Write a Java method that recieves an undeclared ArrayList of integers and an integer as parameters, searches the ArrayList for the integer, returns **true** if found.

A)Use a **while** loop to do the searching. 
B) Try it again but with a **for** loop
C)Try again, but with **for-each** loop
D) (this is hard) Write a Java method that recieves an ArrayList of integers as a parameter and returns the index of the largest integer in the collection.

```
//part a 
int i =0 ;
while (i<500) 
{
    if (values [i] == 3927)
    { 
        system.out.prinln("FOUND IT!");
        break;
    }
    i++; 
}
```

If needed , ill post the code I came up with, please comment if need. I really am having troubles getting this to compile.

Comment: can you post the code

Comment: Sure post the code that you've tried. You should always do that.

Comment: If needed? You should probably read some stuff in the help section. You don't order code.

Comment: People here, can we stop downvoting and give OP a chance to post his code? He has clearly mentioned that in question. This is not a nice welcome to a new user.

Comment: That's a problem statement. What's the actual problem you're having in implementing it?

Comment: +16 reputation for what is essentially "please code this for me", not bad... In a question like this, you should really show the code you have *and* tell what it does and outputs *and* tell what is wrong with it. Then you'll quickly get help, usually.

Comment: Sounds like a question for [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @LeeAllan Isn't Code Review for code you already have, which works, and which you want reviewed?

Comment: Yes, looks like working code to me. Isn't Stack Overflow for code with issues? I see no issues..this question is as much a CR question as it is not a SO question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well the question asks you for part A to write a method that returns true or false so you are missing that part of it, also you're using an array and not the `ArrayList` class, your code should look something like this:

```
public static boolean search(ArrayList<Integer> list, int key) {
    int i = 0;
    while (i < list.size()) {
        if (list.get(i) == key) {
            return true;
        }
        i++;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Okaaaaaaaaay. Let's go from the top my good man.

**The While Loop**

**Documentation:** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html

The while loop is a statement that says the following:

```
while the current statement is true
      keep doing everything inside the brackets.
```

So for example..

```
while(!found) // While found is not equal to true
{
    if(x == 4) found = true;
}
```

As soon as `x` equals `4`, the loop will end. These loops are designed when you *don't know how many times you will loop*. Following this example, you would need to know some details. First, you need to know what the user is looking for, let's call this `value`. Second, you need the list to search, let's call this `myList`. You're returning a `boolean`, so your method is going to look like this:

```
public boolean exists(Integer value)
{
    int position = 0; // The position in myList.

    while(!found && position < myList.size())
    {
        // You're going to work this bit out.
    }

    return false; // Value doesn't exist.
}
```

The trick here is, to set `found` to `true`, if the value in `myList`, at position `position`, is equal to `value`.

---

**The For Loop**

**Documentation**: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

The `For loop` is usually used, when you *know how many times you want to loop*. However, as this is an academic exercise, we'll just ignore that little detail for now. The idea of a for loop is as follows:

```
for(some value x; check x is less/more than some value; do something with x) {
}
```

So for example:

```
for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    System.out.println("Hello: " + x);
}
```

The above loop will print out `Hello:0`, `Hello:1`... `Hello:9`. Now, what you want to do is do the exact same thing you did in the `while loop`, but just wrap it up in a for loop..

```
for(int position = 0; position < myList.size(); position++)
{
    // if value, in myList at position equals value, then return true.
}

return false; // Value doesn't exist.
```

---

**The For-Each Loop**

**Documentation:** http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

The `for-each` loop is very similar to the `for loop`, only the syntax is a little bit nicer, especially when you want to loop through every value in a `List` or `Array`.

```
for(Integer item : myList)
{
    // Creates a variable called value. If item == value, return true.
}

return false;
```

As for the last one, it's all on you buddy, but I'll tell you some tips. You're going to be looping through **every value in your `List`** ***(SEE ABOVE!!!!)***

Answer (score 0):

Here's case A. You should try to figure the rest out on your own if you plan on learning anything.

```
public boolean contains(ArrayList<Integer> haystack, int needle) {
    if (haystack == null) {
        return false;
    }
    // case A
    Iterator<Integer> it = haystack.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        if (it.next().equals(needle)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to use an Iterator? Haystack isn't being modified.

Comment: The OP needs to use a while loop and this seems like the best way to go without maintaining a separate counter variable. But yes, I normally wouldn't use an iterator, or a while loop, in this case.